# What is the best way to include references to my own assemblies in a project template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-template, visual-studio-templates

We have developed a library in C#, and now I wish to create a project template to aid in using the library correctly.

I want new projects to include a reference to the library assembly, but would prefer not to have to deploy the assembly to the GAC, or to depend on the assembly residing in some specific location.

What I am thinking is to include the .dll in the project template .zip file. That means it will end up somewhere inside the project folder of new projects. Perhaps in a folder named Lib. Then the reference hint in the project file can point to that folder. Is that a good idea? What problems might I face down the road?

Is there perhaps some mechanism for including such 3rd party libraries in project templates that I'm not aware of? How have you tackled this? Surely I'm not the first.

Comment: The answer somewhat depends on how you plan on deploying your templates. Are you using VSIX? Are you using MSI (Windows Installer) or other general-purpose deployment technology? Were you planning on just distributing the zip file and providing manual install instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had to address this issue in the past. In one case, it was a logging library that was installed to the GAC, which meant the Reference element simply needed the assembly name. In another case, we installed the library to the file system, created a registry key that contained the location (in case the user got cute and changed the install location on us) and used a [project template wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301%28VS.90%29.aspx) to look up the registry key and populate a replacement item to have the correct location in the Reference's HintPath. (Note: the template wizard approach requires you to install your wizard's assembly to the GAC, which it sounds like you're trying to avoid...)

If you don't want your library to be installed in either the GAC or a specific location, the approach of including the assembly in the project is pretty much your only remaining option. On the positive side, deployment of your project template is fairly straightforward and you don't have to muck with the GAC, custom wizards, etc. On the negative side, if you ever create a new revision of your library, your users will need to update every project's copy of the library.

Comment: What are the implications of installing to the GAC? what are the reasons to avoid it ?

Comment: The primary implication is that the copy of the assembly that is installed to the GAC "wins." That is to say, you may have an updated copy in your app's folder, but as long as the strong name matches, the runtime will preferentially load the copy from the GAC. A roughly analogous example would be as if the GAC'ed assembly's path is the first entry in your PATH variable and you issued a LoadLibrary call. This can result in odd behavior when you are trying to update your binaries and the behavior mysteriously doesn't change.

Comment: Also, although this is not directly a GAC issue, using strong names means that your assembly now requires an assembly that matches the strong name it was compiled against; you'll have to either re-compile or register a publisher policy that redirects binds to a newer version.