# What is the best way to deploy a Template project in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix, project-template

Heyy all =)

We create a custom project template in C# following [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx) topic to force all developers to develop uniformly, all inherit from the same class and receive the same development tools we developed in four separate DLLs and all have the App.config file with default keys etc.
We work on vs2012 or vs2013.

Since I have put the DLLs manually and attach them to come into the same project ZIP file (are that is the right way to do it or somthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122112/1509853) answare?) Now if there are any changes we will have time to re-export it, etc. So we thought the installation project.

Now I'm not sure what type of project to use.
I saw that there are a number of options I will list below and I would love advice about the right, the best, and most appropriate way to do it:

- [Creating Extensions By Using the `VSIX` Project Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885241.aspx) or other [Extensibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19910725/1509853) projects
- The [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) way
- Using [Wizards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) somthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894895/1509853) perfect answare
- One of the project from the [Visual Studio Installer Projects Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx)

Comment: maybe you can create Nuget package and keep updating it by changing the version number?

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa How would `Nuget` work?  Does it actually install anything into the `Visual Studio Extensions` path?  I thought it was limited to the solution folder and below?